# Header value of a standard page

Tags: apex, visualforce, header

This is another generic question. Can a header value be given to a Standard Salesforce page? I would not be able to write a visualforce page for it. It has to be on a standard page

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you might try but no guarantees.

Documentation such as [META for Creating HTTP Headers](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/index_tagsupp_13.html) explains that meta tags can achieve this and Visualforce supports the [Manually Override Automatic  and  Tag Generation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_tags_manual.htm) that should give you control over the `head` section so you could try this:

```
<apex:page ... applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<html>
<head>
<!-- Set your headers here e.g.: -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Author" CONTENT="John Doe">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Other Visualforce tags go here -->
</body>
</html>
```

But you might have to manually add the markup that Visualforce normally generate (found by using your browser's "Inspect" feature) back in to the manually added tags. And I don't know what would happen to the content that Visualforce normally puts in the `head` section.